# Polymer dynamically added elements not styled

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Here is a cut down version of an element I have:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: inline;
            }

            .dark {
                background: black;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>

        <span id="container">
            <content></content>
        </span>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-element',
            ready: function () {
                var containerEl = this.$.container;
                var containerText  = containerEl.textContent.trim();

                // create element
                var clippedSpan = document.createElement('span');
                clippedSpan.textContent = containerText;
                clippedSpan.classList.add("dark");

                // clear container
                containerEl.innerHTML = '';

                containerEl.appendChild(clippedSpan);

                // update the styles
                (this.domHost || Polymer).updateStyles();
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Which is used by adding the following to the index.html page:

```
<my-element>text goes here</my-element>
```

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: inline;
      }
      .dark {
        background: black;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>

    <span id="container">
       <content></content>
     </span>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      ready: function() {
        var containerEl = this.$.container;
        var containerText = containerEl.textContent.trim();

        // create element
        var clippedSpan = document.createElement('span');
        clippedSpan.textContent = containerText;
        clippedSpan.classList.add("dark");

        // clear container
        containerEl.innerHTML = '';

        containerEl.appendChild(clippedSpan);

        // update the styles
        (this.domHost || Polymer).updateStyles();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<my-element>text goes here</my-element>
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MPTwd2mYbnnjsu0REQmT?p=preview)

I can see that the `span` element created does have the class `dark` applied to it but none of the styles for the `dark` class are actually being applied. This must be because it is being dynamically added as a child. I have tried called the `updateStyles` function on both `this` and the global `Polymer` object to no avail.

How do I make sure that the styles are applied correctly?

The reason for using the `<content>` tag instead of an attribute is purely for simplicity.

Comment: Found the problem, though not the solution yet. Problem is that your dynamically created element is not getting insert into the shadow-dom of your element. If you manually add `style-scope my-element` to the class attribute of your dynamically created element everything will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api)

> Polymer provides a custom API for manipulating DOM such that local DOM and light DOM trees are properly maintained.
>
> Note: All DOM manipulation must use this API, as opposed to DOM API directly on nodes.

```
         Polymer.dom(containerEl).appendChild(clippedSpan);
```